# Overriding a private function within a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, closures

I have this puzzler. I've downloaded a jQuery plugin that has the following construction

```
(function($, undefined) {
 function a() {
  ...
 }

 $.fn.fullCalendar = function(options) {
  ...
  var avar = a(); 
  ...
 }
})(jQuery);
```

and my taks is to modify the plugin (I need to override the 'a' function) but I can't touch the core and I need to modify it from an external file. So... the problem is I don't know is there at all a way to access an unnamed closure and the second if I'd be able to will I be able to override a private function within it?

To be more specific: the plugin is: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar and I need to override the 'daySegHTML' function within the core.

Thank You for any advices.

Comment: That's completely impossible.

Comment: Why are you trying to override the function instead of writing around it? Worst case, modify the source code directly.

Comment: What do You mean by 'writing around it' ?

Comment: a() is part of fullCalendar(). I'd be like trying to override a specific if block or loop in a function. Can't do it. You'd have to override the whole thing.

Comment: So how can I modify this part of the functionality of that plugin?

Comment: If you want to modify just `a()`, then modify the source itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override functions in closures (at least not if they aren't exposed to the outside somehow). The only chance to modify it, is modifying the source code itself (if it's license allows it).

Closures are used to "hide" functionality from the user. It is probably the only reason why there are powerful javascript libraries like google maps out there.

Comment: Ok, I'll just try to find another way to achieve my goal. Thank You all for the advices.

Comment: For reference, here's how the function is actually defined (which confirms it can't be overridden) https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/common/DayEventRenderer.js#L118